# Jade/Node database data not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm attemting to create an application to make restraunt reservations with Node, but currently my data from the database is not showing on the page. Here is the jade file of the page that is meant to display the data:

```
extends layout

block content
h1.
    Reservations
ul
    each reservation in reservations
        li= reservation.lastName
        li= reservation.numberOfPeople
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/reservations', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('freshStart');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('reservations', {
            "reservations" : docs
        });
    });
});

router.get('/makeReservation', function(req, res){
    res.render('makeReservation', { title: 'Make a reservation'});
});

router.post('/makeReservation', function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;

    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var numberOfPeople = req.body.numberOfPeople;
    var time = req.body.myTime;
    var date = req.body.myDate;

    var collection = db.get('freshStart');

    collection.insert({
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "numberOfPeople" : numberOfPeople,
        "time" : time,
        "date" : date
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database", err.toString());
        } else {
            res.redirect("reservations");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Yet when I load the page, it only shows the title but no database info. I've queried the data in cmd and it comes up with two entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to `console.log(docs)`

Comment: Thats gives me an empty array

Comment: So the problem is that, check the `freshStart`collection is not empty

Comment: I can't print the console info its way too long

Comment: What am I looking for to prove that it has info in it?

Comment: Doesn't matter I fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was I was refrencing the wrong part of the database. This was my code:

```
router.get('/reservations', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('freshStart');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('reservations', {
            "reservations" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

What I should have been doing is this:

```
router.get('/reservations', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('reservations');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('reservations', {
            "reservations" : docs
        });
    });
});
```